# VBA - Dump data from existing connection

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

So I have a workbook that someone else created to which there are already connections created. One of the connections retrieves data from an access database and then outputs it to a pivottable.

If I goto **Data > Existing Connections > Select my connection (the access one) > click open > Table > New worksheet**, it will output the entire table which is exactly what I want; however, I want to do this with VBA automated. If I use the macro recorder it ends up with:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=4, Source:=ActiveWorkbook. _
    Connections("Access G183"), Destination:=Range("$A$1")).TableObject
    .RowNumbers = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshStyle = 1
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Data"
    .Refresh
End With
End Sub
```

Whenever I run the macro again, it errors at either the .ListObject.DisplayName or .Refresh lines. If I comment these out, then it simply loads no data.  Has anyone found a way to automate this before? The tricky part is that the workbook no longer has the original database.

Comment: Have you tried assigning the worksheet to an object and then acting upon that object directly instead of using the active sheet?  This would allow you to break the steps up, which might make a difference, especially the refresh.

Comment: @BillHileman Yes I have tried that. You mean simply declaring the worksheet as a variable first and then using that right?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  What is the error that it is reporting?

Comment: It is unclear (to me at least) if the newly added worksheet is also the currently active worksheet.

Comment: @BillHileman Stating that the original data location of the access database can't be accessed.

Comment: @Yorik Everything is being done within the same workbook. No others are open

Comment: You may need to refresh the connection and/or close and re-open the connection with the access database.  It may be placing a passive lock on the data.

Comment: @BillHileman That is the problem. I do not have access to the original access database. That was on someone's C drive so I can't refresh. The data still "lives" within my workbook though as shown above I can manually dump it, just not with VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I could find was to do the following:

1. Create a pivot table from VBA in the original workbook on a new worksheet
2. Make the pivot table look exactly how I want it still within the original workbook
3. "Flatten out" the pivot table by copying the columns and rows it occupies to a new tab. This eliminates any unnecessary data to not waste memory. If I didn't do this step, my computer would actually run out of memory for copying the entire data set.
4. Copy the flattened out worksheet to the new workbook.

A little bit of a work around but this worked for me so I hope it does for others too.